# How to display rows in heroku database?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

This page says with this command heroku pg:psql you can see see all the rows.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#provision-a-database

but after using this command I got something like this.

[image]

Comment: I want to see my rows and columns in my database just like phpmyadmin shows us the data. Sorry, I am new to the heroku and postgresql I don't anything about it. I just followed the tutotial to deploy my website to heroku but the tutorial of heroku does'not say anything about how to display data. Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will have to take a backup of the hosted Postgres DB add-on and restore it to your local machine. Here's a useful article from their site.

[Postgres-import-export](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export)

Comment: I pgweb that solved my problem. So if anyone wants to look at the data deployed on Heroku. You need to search for pgweb.